# SEGMENT_UNKNOWN error while acessing SAP backend via JCO-connector

Tags: java, abap, jco, idoc, boomi

I'm trying to connect to a SAP system via Java Middleware (Dell Boomi) to inspect existing document types.
When inspecting a base IDOC Type (e.g. ORDERS05) everything works ok.
When trying to inspect a custom type (e.g. ZORDERS05) I get a rather obscure exception from the java JCO classes:

```
Feb 25, 2016 6:56:56 PM CET WARNING [com.boomi.connector.sap.browse.SAPIDocSchemaBuilder buildSchema] Unable to find IDoc base type: ZORDERS05, extension: 
com.sap.conn.jco.AbapException: (126) SEGMENT_UNKNOWN: SEGMENT_UNKNOWN Message 257 of class EA type E, Par[1]: ZHEADER, Par[2]: 740
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc$JavaRfcClient.execute(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:2083)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ClientConnection.execute(ClientConnection.java:1185)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ClientConnection.execute(ClientConnection.java:1014)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.RfcDestination.execute(RfcDestination.java:1458)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.RfcDestination.execute(RfcDestination.java:1428)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.AbapFunction.execute(AbapFunction.java:332)
    at com.boomi.connector.sap.SAPConnection.executeFunction(SAPConnection.java:103)
    at com.boomi.connector.sap.browse.SAPIDocSchemaBuilder.buildSchema(SAPIDocSchemaBuilder.java:49)
    at com.boomi.connector.sap.browse.SAPSchemaBrowser.buildIDocProfile(SAPSchemaBrowser.java:210)
    at com.boomi.connector.sap.browse.SAPSchemaBrowser.browse(SAPSchemaBrowser.java:84)
    at com.boomi.connector.custom.CustomConnectorBrowseAction.browse(CustomConnectorBrowseAction.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.boomi.util.ClassUtil$InvokerWithClassLoader.invoke(ClassUtil.java:360)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.browse(Unknown Source)
    at com.boomi.connector.BrowseMessageHandler.handle(BrowseMessageHandler.java:116)
    at com.boomi.container.core.MessagePollerThread$BaseTask.handleMessage(MessagePollerThread.java:657)
    at com.boomi.container.core.MessagePollerThread$AsyncTask.run(MessagePollerThread.java:742)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any hint on how to troubleshoot this problem?
SAP side the objects seem to be really identical (both base types, no extension etc...)

Comment: Don't have a clue to what its about but may be [this](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3436578) or [this](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/191133/why-does-the-websphere-adapter-for-sap-get-the-com.html) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note from  Ravindra HV  is correct, this problem is caused from a misconfiguration on the SAP side.
In order to fix this the SAP team had to release the custom segments (ZHEADER) inside the custom IDOC type.
See answer to this: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3436578